# move a specific column down using awk

Tags: awk

how can I move second column one row down as shown in the below example?

```
> input
n an na na
a ae 1 2 3
b be 3 2 1
c    4 4 4

> output
n  na na
a an 1 2 3
b be 3 2 1
c be 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this awk one-liner does the job for you:

```
awk '{t=$2;$2=p;p=t}7' file
```